# Laravel & SQL запрос: топ 1 пользователь по кол-ву постов в каждом месяце

Tags: php, sql, laravel

**Задача**: получить ответ на вопрос "***Кто в каждом месяце опубликовал наибольшее число идей за текущий год***". На выходе должны получить массив с 12-ью месяцами, где каждый месяц содержит одного пользователя с кол-вом публикаций. 
Что-то типа такого:

```
'0' => ["author_id" => 69, "count" => 2, "month" => 1],
'1' => ["author_id" => 44, "count" => 33, "month" => 2],
'2' => ["author_id" => 38, "count" => 10, "month" => 3],
```

или

```
'0' => ["author_id" => 69, "count" => 2],
'1' => ["author_id" => 44, "count" => 33],
'2' => ["author_id" => 38, "count" => 10],
...
'11' => ["author_id" => 4, "count" => 41],
```

**Текущее решение**:

```
Idea::OnlyMyCompany()
        ->select(DB::raw('author_id'), DB::raw('count(author_id) as count, MONTH(created_at) month'))
        ->whereYear('created_at', '=', $year)
        ->groupBy('author_id', 'month')
        ->orderBy('month')
        ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

**Текущий результат**:

```
'0' => ["author_id" => 69, "count" => 2, "month" => 1],
'1' => ["author_id" => 33, "count" => 1, "month" => 1],
'2' => ["author_id" => 16, "count" => 1, "month" => 1],
'3' => ["author_id" => 44, "count" => 33, "month" => 2],
'4' => ["author_id" => 92, "count" => 16, "month" => 2]
.....
```

Как видно, мы получаем всех пользователей с их кол-во публикаций. А необходимо только наибольшего.

Возможные пути решения:

1. Отфильтровать текущий результат в php
2. Подкорректировать SQL запрос

Прошу подсказать решение.

Answer (score 0):

Если предложение WHERE определяет предикат для фильтрации строк, то предложение HAVING применяется после группировки. Попробуйте использовать having max.